# iOS - UITableView Crash

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, didreceivememorywarning

I have images loading into UITableViewCell. The images are not big in size - each one is probably only 6 KB.

There are 500 rows however. When I scroll, it starts slow at first and gives me the memory warning message, but then after a few more scrolls, the app crashes. I've also used instruments and it shows that the memory usage keeps getting higher and higher as I scroll! Could it be that `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier` is not working properly or maybe I should somehow 'nil' the images?!

By the way, I have closed ALL the other apps on my device and I have more than 1.5 GB free on my iPod Touch.

Here's the code for configuring cells:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    int cellNumber = indexPath.row + 1;
    NSString *cellImage1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"c%i.png", cellNumber];
    UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:cellImage1];

    [cell.imageView setImage:theImage];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: // I'm using ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) by the way.
I restarted the device and the problem with the crash kinda got solved. but the memory usage still gets higher (instruments shows it)

Answer (score 0):

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] 
            initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
            reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] 
                         initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                         reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

What's going on here? You're reallocating the same memory twice.

Comment: I'm using ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) and it doesn't allow me to use:
return [cell autorelease];

Comment: Why are you reallocating cell twice after the initial instantiation?

Comment: sorry it was a typo! fixed that in the question. (wasn't in the code)